# Is it possible to Select a record for processing, if the selected record plus the two adjacent records add up to a certain quantity?

Tags: c#, group-by

I would like to loop thru my records by Price (records are inserted by price, down to the penny) upon selecting a record, also grab the records one penny above and one penny below (if available), and total the Quantity.  If the Quantity of these combined records is greater than a value, select it for further processing.
I think Grouping would work, but I'm not sure where to start.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
// Query the List
     var CombinedQtyGT5K = (from a in TrackPrice
                                           orderby a.Quantity descending
                                           where a.Quantity > 5000
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               a.Price,
                                               a.Quantity,
                                           });

                foreach (var myprice in CombinedQtyGT5K )
                {   
                    //Process prices
                }               


public class PriceLevel
{
    public decimal Price         { get; set; }
    public int Quantity          { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There might be a way to do this with LINQ, but it is likely to be harder to understand and maintain. Why don't you just write the whole thing as a For loop? You will get access to before and after indexes which means it would be trivial to add additional complex ranking aggregations and clauses in a way that is easy to modify.

Comment: I agree. LINQ is meant to provide shortcuts in order to make things easier, not create unnecessary challenges. Remember, LINQ is not more efficient at its core.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing would be the grouping

```
var selected;
var group = CombinedQtyGT5K.GroupBy(x => x.Price);
//Not sure if you want to group it this way, cant comment so ill be guessing some 
//things in this answer
```

Then add the loop

```
int c = group.count();
for(i=0; i < c, i++){
//add validation if up and down records avalible
//if c > 0 for example
if(group[c].Quantity + group[c-1].Quantity + group[c+1].Quantity > MinValue ){
selected = group[c];
//call the method to do your proccesing here
  } 
}
```

Comment: You could change the for loop with a foreach and use the List<T>.IndexOf Method to check the up and down records of the element evaluated

Comment: My fault, the quantities are already totaled, so it looks like you're in agreement that the Loop is the way to go.  Thanks

Comment: ... totaled by price

Comment: Roger, i think the loop is the best way. simple and effective

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help